# Session Cookies and CORS. Cookie not being set correctly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, cookies, cors

My problem:
I have a server and an app running on 2 different domains.

1. Node.js Express API on Heroku
2. Vue.JS app from an S3 bucket with CloudFront

calling POST /login works fine and I'm being returned a cookie.
calling GET /projects I'm met with a 401.

if you check the request and responses you will see that the 2nd projects call sends an incorrect cookie. It seems the cookie just isn't being set correctly.

Login call Request

```
Host: ***-***.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 56
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin: https://***.********.nl
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://***.********.nl/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,de;q=0.6
```

Login call Response

```
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://***.********.nl
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 103
Etag: W/"67-AcqjF7Jne+FP4OtwKOHMGKpgbHY"
Set-Cookie: SessionId=s%3AyWaalYxA-qU2KY3gvGbg0x1K3Ro7jjwI.d%2B8CZS3m6YCKL0X1TQSlm2TW3ihUaV%2BnfGpj3SsylEE; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Date: Sat, 18 Jul 2020 18:26:41 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Projects call Request

```
GET /api/v1/projects/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ***-***.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Origin: https://***.********.nl
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://***.********.nl/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,de;q=0.6
Cookie: SessionId=s%3Am5eOkHADAMTBXXdbnB3WwaEjsM8M6uqZ.8Ew5jim5S0iXei4DvucMZ%2BQv8LbUYteBE%2Bt6pVvtzEM
```

Projects call Response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://***.********.nl
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 45
Etag: W/"2d-dzHmdZiZSbYibOdmu6CEgThdGrs"
Date: Sat, 18 Jul 2020 18:26:42 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Express CORS Configuration

```
this.app.use(cors({
      origin: ["https://********.nl", "https://***.********.nl", /\.********\.nl$/], 
      credentials: true
    }))
```

Passport.js Configuration

```
    cookie: {
      production: true,
      maxAge: null,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
    }
```

CloudFront Configuration

[image: CloudFront Configuration]

Comment: Are your frontend and backend using the same domain?

Comment: @jellycsc they are on two different domains. Edited my post to better reflect

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit speculative but it was much too long to fit into a comment so I've tried to frame it as an answer instead...

The key question here is where does that other cookie come from? I see two possibilities:

1. There's another request, after the login request, that sets it to that new value.
2. The other cookie was there all along. It's an old cookie that was set at some point in the past and the new cookie is just being ignored.

One thing you haven't mentioned in the question is whether the second request always sends the same cookie. That would allow us to differentiate between the two scenarios I outlined above.

I notice that the original login request doesn't include a `cookie` request header. That's interesting because if the rogue cookie is an old cookie then it should also be included on that request.

Based on all that, my theory is that you aren't setting the `withCredentials` flag to `true` on the login request. That would explain why there's no `cookie` request header and also explains why the returned `set-cookie` response header is being ignored.

Just to be clear, you need to set `withCredentials` on both requests. It isn't sufficient just to set it on the second request. Given that the second request includes a `cookie` header it would appear that the second request does already have `withCredentials` set.

I also suggest you take a look at `chrome://settings/siteData`. That will show you exactly what cookies are set and also allows you to delete specific cookies. Try deleting the relevant cookie and then see whether it gets set when you login.

Comment: I suspect it's option 2 but the cookie is always there even incognito. Both the API service and the call have withCredentials set, however. I will try the siteData suggestion and report back